# Update ListView from another

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qabstractlistmodel

I'm making a card game which has 4 slots of cards with a capacity of 5 each. I'm using `ListView` to represent each slot. Let me explain code first then my problem.

```
class ClientCard : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int code;       // card code
    int location;   // zone in which card is located
    ...
    ClientCard* equipTarget;
    QSet<ClientCard*> equipped;
    ...
};

class ClientCardModel : public QAbstractListModel 
{
    enum CardRoles {
        CodeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, 
        LocationRole
        }
    ...
    QList<ClientCard*> m_list;
};
```

`ClientCardModel` has a list of `ClientCard` for `ListView` and roles to transfer code and other member to QML. Let me represent each `ListView` with a zone (like zone1, zone2 etc). In the game a card can be equipped with other cards in other zones. Cards equipped on a card is stored in `QSet<> equipped` and a card equipping a card is stored in `equipTarget`. When one hover over a card in a zone, cards equipping it in other zones should be highlighted using an image till the mouse remains on the card.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not at home, no laptop here, cannot provide an example right now. If you can wait 24h, I'll be back, otherwise let me know what's not clear and I'll reply.

Comment: Code will be helpful.

Comment: Absolutely, busy at work, maybe I'll have a chance tomorrow, I'm sorry.

Comment: Whenever you have time.

Comment: Would you provide me a sample code??

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it fits your requirements.

Reply reviewed, just woken up, sorry. :-)

You can have delegates in your view covered with `MouseArea`.
Once a card is hovered, you can set an internal parameter accessible from within the `delegate` that reflects the state of the equipped card (hovered/not hovered).
The delegate itself will react to the change of that parameter, so that each other card equipping the hovered one would react as well.

In other therms, hovering should change some exported parameter (this can be achieved maybe by means of a `MouseArea`) and delegates should be designed so that they react on that parameter changes to show whatever you want.

Comment: The first problem with it is, how to transfer `ClientCard* equipTarget` and `QSet<ClientCard*> equipped` to qml, so that qml might know which card to  equip.

Comment: Exporting properties is not as difficult, here the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html. The equipped set doesn't need to be exported, does it? I've understood that you were interested in exposing the `equipTarget` property to know when it's hovered.

Comment: Actually there are three `QSet`, all of which are to be exported. Yes exporting `equipTarget` is not difficult.

Comment: OK, thus you can define a proxy object for a set, easily define on it a bunch of methods to query the underlying set and export the proxy from the card object. I'm not sure that exporting directly the set object will solve the problem, but you can have also a try without any proxy at all before to spend your time on it. Obviously, by defining a proxy you get the full control on what the owner can do on the set, because it's up to you to decide which properties and methods should be exposed.

Comment: It might work (will require a bit of work though). I'll update you with my progress.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot figure out an easier method that require less work. Another approach could be setting a parameter on an outer container to notify that a card has been selected, so that delegates can react to it. Anyway, you still need to export the target card for a check. That said, I don't like much that solution, where an outer container behaves like a channel to deliver information about selected card...

Comment: In the answer you've said "delegates should be designed so that they react on that parameter changes to show whatever you want". Let us have 5 array of size 5 each, representing state of cards(hovered/ not hovered). How do you suggest to bind each element of array to each element of `ListView`.